# Random characters always return zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this snippet it will generate mixed words and numbers randomly but i'm wondering why it always return zero in second character? if you click refresh button it always return 0 in second position. any idea?

```js
$(function() {
  var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var myLength = 4;

  function Captcha() {
    $('#Captcha').html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $('#Captcha').append(word + i++);
    }
  }
    Captcha();
 $('#reCaptchaRefresh').click(function(){
  Captcha();
  });
});
```

```css
#Captcha {
border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#reCaptchaRefresh {
clear: both;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Captcha" ></div>
<div id="reCaptchaRefresh">
Refresh
</div>
```

Comment: it always has a 2 at the end as well, because that's the value of i in the first loop (0) and the second (and last) loop (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` will cause the problem . since you are appending `i++` at the end of every character . and loop will also run only `2 times` .

```js
$(function() {
  var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var myLength = 4;

  function Captcha() {
    $('#Captcha').html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $('#Captcha').append(word);
                      //   ^^^^^ edited here
    }
  }
    Captcha();
 $('#reCaptchaRefresh').click(function(){
  Captcha();
  });
});
```

```css
#Captcha {
border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#reCaptchaRefresh {
clear: both;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Captcha" ></div>
<div id="reCaptchaRefresh">
Refresh
</div>
```

Comment: Not me, but I was about to comment that "code dumps are not useful answers" (the original answer was *purely* a code dump; then you ninja-edited at least a word or two of explanation [though still *really* vague] into the opening). Take the time to answer properly **before** posting.

Comment: there's no prize for **first** answer - the best answer is a well thought out answer with explanation - I downvoted (now reversed due to *some* effort on your part) because it was a pure code dump, and even the first edit did not make this a particularly useful answer -interestingly, no answer, and not even the OP seems to have noticed that the last character is always a 2

Comment: @iXplo: It was a code dump *in* a snippet. :-) AKA a game of "spot the difference." Explanations are important.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because you're appending `i` to the output string. You're also incrementing `i` twice in each iteration. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ0123456789abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var myLength = 4;

  function Captcha() {
    $('#Captcha').empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $('#Captcha').append(word); // Note the removal of the concatenation and '++' here
    }
  }

  $('#reCaptchaRefresh').click(Captcha).trigger('click');
});
```

```css
#Captcha {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#reCaptchaRefresh {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Captcha"></div>
<div id="reCaptchaRefresh">
  Refresh
</div>
```